# Game Center list all achievements for current user

Tags: ios, game-center

I would really like to know what information can I get for logged in user from Game Center.

**Is it possible to get all achievements that user has in Game center**? And I do mean all of them, including the achievements in other games?

**What about all the games user has played?**

I cannot find any information about this in [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html), so I am assuming Apple keeps this to themselves.

**What information is available to us, outside of our own application?**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I hope not - you have no need to know that info. But I would be interested if that is not the case +1.

Comment: I need to know the information, not only for displaying in a single app, but I could also then display it in another app. Steam provides such API. :)